# `WebP` tools is not found while running `pana` tool against dart package

Tags: flutter, dart, webp, pub.dev

While I was running [pana](https://pub.dev/packages/pana) to analyze a Dart package, an error stating that `webpinfo`, `cwebp`, and `gif2webp` were not found:

```
INFO       Running `webpinfo C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pana_7ed394ff\.\doc/assets/animated_example.webp`...
'webpinfo' tool not found.INFO       Running `cwebp C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pana_7ed394ff\.\doc/assets/animated_example.webp -o C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\365b6b14\gen\animated_example.webp`...
'cwebp' tool not found.INFO       Running `gif2webp C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pana_7ed394ff\.\doc/assets/animated_example.webp -o C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\365b6b14\gen\animated_example.webp`...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the mentioned tools are parts of [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) Library, according to the [official website](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/)

> WebP is a modern image format that provides superior lossless and lossy compression for images on the web. Using WebP, webmasters and web developers can create smaller, richer images that make the web faster.

To solve the error, download the latest version of the library from [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download), and install it according to the instructions on the same link.

I have installed it on windows by just adding the path of the library until the `bin/` folder to the Command Prompt (CMD) from the Environmental Variables settings on the windows as per [this method](https://linuxhint.com/add-directory-to-path-environment-variables-windows/).

I think the same solution would work for macOS and Linux by exporting the path to the terminal.